# Sort list from web

Tags: python

I'm doing a lou's list that contains information about classes from the web and I want to create a function that sorts a list containing each instructor listed in Lou’s List for the given department. So if I call the function `print(instructors("EAST"))` the function would print `[‘Benedetta Lomi’, ‘Michiko Wilson’, ‘Staff’]`. Here is what I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
link="http://stardock.cs.virginia.edu/louslist/Courses/view/CS"
stream=urllib.request.urlopen(link)
for line in stream:
    decoded = line.strip().decode("UTF-8")      
#print(decoded)
    entry = decoded.split(";")
```

Comment: what does east refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do an alphanumeric sort on a list like this:

```
entry = sorted(decoded.split(";"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to parse the uri stream.

Then sort the list of tuples by the relevant field

```
data.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[<index>])
```

Finally use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter your results and print the relevant tuple field.